# Porqué se generan imágenes en blanco usando la librería phantomjs?

Tags: php, tcpdf, phantomjs

Resulta que estoy generando un informe en pdf con unas imágenes que se descargan de una url, uso la librería phantomjs en PHP para hacer la captura , pero resulta que esta captura esta en blanco, se genera pero en blanco, aumento el tiempo de renderización y sigue igual, les agradezco si me ayudan buscando una solución.
///////////////////////////////////////función que realiza la descarga

```
function download_graph ($url,$name){
    $url = str_replace ("&","@",$url);

    $archive = "/var/www/html/reports/automatic_reports/resources/screenshot.js";

    $name_file = "/var/www/html/reports/automatic_reports/resources/capturas_test/".$name.".png";

    // Ejecuta la sentencia  para hacer la descarga
    shell_exec("/opt/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs $archive $url $name_file ");
```

/////////////////////////////////archivo.js que realiza la captura

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system'),
address, output;
address = system.args[1];
var address = address.replace(/@/gi,"&");// Modifica la URL para tener en cuenta el simbolo & que fue remplazado por el simbolo @ en PHP


output = system.args[2];
delay = 15000;// Asigna un tiempo de espera para renderizar la pagina.
page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };//define tamaño de la pantalla
//page.clipRect = { top: 300, left: 100, width: 720, height: 360 };//define que parte se hace el recorte
page.open(address, function(status) {

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        page.render(system.args[2]);
        phantom.exit();
    }, delay);
});
```

Comment: El error no necesariamente está en la renderización. Podría ser que la imagen no existe, está dañada, no se localiza, etc. ¿Podrías mostrarnos algo de código para poder ayudarte mejor?

Comment: vale, ya cargue el código que tengo en la pregunta

Comment: ¿Alguna razón en específico por la cuál estás usando específicamente phantomjs en lugar de una herramienta nativa como wget?